# Most .onion sites I am trying to access are unavailable: Why and how can I solve this?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, website

I think that 80% of the onion sites I'm trying to reach are most of the time (if not always) unavailable. It tells me that

> Firefox can't estabilish a connection to the server at *****.onion

and

> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.

I'm running TBB 4.0.1 for x64 Linux and I don't use firewalls or proxy servers.

Why does it happen and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is no way to access them if they go down. Some servers after offline but come back for various reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you connect to [Tor Check](https://check.torproject.org/)? Does it confirm that you are connected to Tor? If so, then the hidden services you are trying to access are down.

> I think that 80% of the onion sites I'm trying to reach are most of the time (if not always) unavailable.

This is pretty common. Torland isn't known for its stability. Hidden services come and go without any trace all the time. Try connecting sometime later.

Comment: Yes,It confirms that I am connected to Tor.So the servers are down and it's not the connection's fault?Does it mean that I cannot do anything to access the websites?

Comment: 80% is quite a lot; it's possible they all just happen to be down, but given that we've had another similar question recently I suspect it's not a coincidence and there's something else going on here.

Comment: Now,I would rather say 90% of them won't work,as I try to access them almost daily...

Comment: @VIPaul Every now and then a scare about Tor security happens and site owners (or hosts) go offline for some time. With the recent news of a major infamous hidden site being shut down by a three letter agency, it is to be expected. I suspect that they will be back online after things quiet down. Then again, I haven't seen the statististics, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @VIPaul You might also check that your system clock is set correctly, as someone suggested in a duplicate question. Maybe it thinks the descriptors are being published in the future and isn't connecting?

Comment: I am having this problem too, but in my case, chrome shows that it is connected to orbit, but doesn't open any onion sites, I mean any site, not one or two but I can't access any site even when connected to orbit. But if I try to access through a new APN with for proxy and port, the site opens fine. Please help me.