# How do you connect to onion websites

Tags: help

Every website I try, Tor says it cant connect to it. When I start Tor it says congratulations you have connected to the tor network!  Then it says your ip address appears to be. xxx.xx.xxx.xx. So why wont it let me connect to onion sites. Below is what I get This is just an example of what it says Ive tried over 50 websites.

> **Unable to connect**
>
> ***Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at eqt5g4fuenphqinx.onion.***
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>      If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>      If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/most-onion-sites-i-am-trying-to-access-are-unavailable-why-and-how-can-i-solve).

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve a .onion address, you will need to make your web browser use Socks5 remote DNS, since only the Tor system is aware of .onion addresses. You will need to configure your browser accordingly. Since I do not know what browser you are using, I will show a Firefox example (since TBB uses Firefox by default anyway):

[image]